# Properly read/convert received bluetooth data from Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

I have an Android device sending data to an Arduino HCO5 bluetooth module, my Android code is as(truncated):

```
OutputStream.write(bytes.getBytes()); //bytes here is a string
```

The Android documentation says `write()` receives `byte[]` format. Now when I receive this data on the serial monitor, for string "H" sent I get `0 128 248`, for string "1" `120 128` etc.
I'm not really sure what this is however I assumed it was the parts of a byte array so I wrote this code to stuff them in an array:

```
int position = 0;
byte bigVal[] = {0};
byte val;

while (Serial.available() > 0) {  
    val = Serial.read();
    bigVal[position] = val;
    position++;
 }
```

Afterwards I tried converting back to a string using `String myString = String(myByteArray)` with no luck. How do I convert back to appropriate string/char please?

Comment: Have you tried `Serial.readString()`(https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString)

Comment: Apparently my code for storing the byte data is incorrect(writes to memory beyond the array) so nothing after will work, working on a solution for that first